# I use setState() but it didn't show me the new point update

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to show my new point and tier when data changed on database. And i use setState to do that thing but it didn't work.

Here my code:

```
String? point;
  String? tier;
  Future<void> getInfomation() async {
    List response = await Future.wait([
      MemberTierServices().getMemberTier(),
      MemberShipCurrencyService().getMemberShipCurrency()
    ]);
    String nameTier = response[0].name;
    String pointBalance = response[1].pointsBalance.toString();
    setState(() {
      tier = nameTier;
      point = pointBalance;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Please include the response you are receiving

Comment: This is incomplete code.  Please show your entire State and initState (down to the build beginning).